# Drag and Drop feature in a New Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a drag and drop feature in my plugin. The idea is that it should work similar to the widgets style already being used in wordpress.
Can anyone provide me guidance on how to use this existing code?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery ui sortable for this: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/